# Implications of FirebaseAuth credentials in an Android .apk

Tags: android, google, reverse-engineering, credentials

I'm currently looking at an .apk for Android and I came across some hard-coded credentials. Apparently these are used for something called `FireBaseAuth`, which seems to be a Google service.

I'm not very familiar with the Android app development and don't know what the FireBase service is exactly used for.

Is it common to save hard-coded credentials for the service in the app?

What can be done with the credentials?

The credentials do not reflect any information affiliated with me.

*edit:* I did come across [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37678876/6921751), stating something about identifiers, but no clear answer.